Docker secret files not mounting
I am trying to mount the config.toml and credentials.toml from the ${HOME}/.cargo directory to a target directory in a docker file. For some reason, the files are never mounted.
Command:
docker build --secret id=config,src=${HOME}/.cargo/config.toml --secret id=credentials,src=${HOME}/.cargo/credentials.toml ./ -t andynopol/babylon-registry-manager --no-cache --progress=plain

Dockerfile mount command:
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=config,target=/usr/local/cargo/config.toml \
    --mount=type=secret,id=credentials,target=/usr/local/cargo/credentials.toml

RUN ls -la /usr/local/cargo/

Output:
#14 [builder  5/11] RUN ls -la /usr/local/cargo/
#14 0.079 total 20
#14 0.079 drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Oct 30 20:58 .
#14 0.079 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 19 20:03 ..
#14 0.079 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Oct 19 20:03 bin
#14 0.079 -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  308 Oct 19 20:03 env
#14 DONE 0.1s

I am using docker 27.2.0
What am I doing wrong?

The problem that is not explained enough is that the secrets scope starts and ends within the run command. So in order to make them a permanent config, you need to save them as a temp file and copy them in your destination:

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=config,target=<DISK_CONFIG> \
    --mount=type=secret,id=credentials,target=<DISC_CREDENTIALS> \
    cp <TEMP_CONFIG> <PERMANENT_CONFIG_LOCATION> && cp <TEMP_CREDENTIALS> <PERMANENT_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION>

Feel free to add a cleaner syntax.
